# Backup and Restore SQL Server Database With Compression When comprehension is not supported

Tags: sql-server, nuget, ssms, backup, restore

I need update backup and restore module on my app because it is consuming lot disk space.

The module run query for backup but not work in express editions of SQL Server. I need fix the module and make backup with compression in any SQL version, for not reinstall the actually SQL instances.

**SQL backup query with compression**

```
BACKUP DATABASE [MyDataBase] TO  DISK = N'C:\backup\MyDataBase20210829T213904.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'MyDataBase-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10
```

**SQL error**

> Msg 1844, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> BACKUP DATABASE WITH COMPRESSION is not supported on Express Edition

Answer (score 0):

You can always make a script of your database. This will not only take lesser space but will also give you a lot of options such as different versions of SQL Server, Schema only script, schema and Data script, triggers with script.

All you have to do is

> Right Click on DB > Tasks > Generate Scripts...

[image: Step 1]

Then follow the wizard to this screen

[image: Step 2]

In advanced select the options according to your requirements.

[image: Step 3]

Run the script in your desired server to restore everything. Booom!!

Comment: Thanks but i need backup with data. Your query only restore the database without data.

Comment: You see the "Type of Data:"? It's default is "Schema only" you can change it to "Schema and Data" to get backup script with data